# Merge 2 XML files from item level and down

Tags: xml

I am trying to merge 2 XML files and I have looked into similar cases on this site, but not found the solution.

Basically, 2 XML files with same structure but comes from 2 sources and I would like to combine them into one XML file and save it locally. 
What I am trying to achieve is this: 
Drop the header part from the file 2 and file 1 and create a new with same structure but with custom info.
Add just the item part (and its subitems) into the combined file
And be able to sort the result on pubDate so the item sort descending
And then save the file locally
And all with C#

To illustrate

FILE 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
  <channel>
    <title>File 1</title>
    <link>http://www.somewhere.com/</link>
    <description>Feed from the source</description>
    <image>
      <title>My image</title>
      <link>http://www.somewhere.com/</link>
      <url>http://www.somewhere.com/images/redesign/graphics/logos/logo-small.png</url>
      <width>128</width>
      <height>23</height>
    </image>
    <language>
    </language>
    <ttl>15</ttl>
    <item>
      <title>Article 1</title>
      <pubDate>Fri, 09 Dec 2011 13:24:27 +0100</pubDate>
      <description>Description here</description>
      <guid>http://www.somewhere.com/pressroom/article1</guid>
      <link>http://www.somewhere.com/pressroom/article1</link>
      <dc:creator>Someone</dc:creator>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

FILE 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
  <channel>
    <title>File 2</title>
    <link>http://www.somewhere2.com/</link>
    <description>Feed from the other source</description>
    <image>
      <title>My image</title>
      <link>http://www.somewhere2.com/</link>
      <url>http://www.somewhere2.com/images/redesign/graphics/logos/logo-small.png</url>
      <width>128</width>
      <height>23</height>
    </image>
    <language>
    </language>
    <ttl>15</ttl>
    <item>
      <title>Article 2</title>
      <pubDate>Fri, 11 Dec 2011 13:27:27 +0100</pubDate>
      <description>Description here</description>
      <guid>http://www.somewhere2.com/pressroom/article2</guid>
      <link>http://www.somewhere2.com/pressroom/article2</link>
      <dc:creator>Someone else</dc:creator>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

RESULT FILE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
  <channel>
    <title>Merged File</title>
    <link>http://www.somewhere3.com/</link>
    <description>Feed from the merged source</description>
    <image>
      <title>My image</title>
      <link>http://www.somewhere3.com/</link>
      <url>http://www.somewhere3.com/images/redesign/graphics/logos/logo-small.png</url>
      <width>128</width>
      <height>23</height>
    </image>
    <language>
    </language>
    <ttl>15</ttl>
    <item>
      <title>Article 2</title>
      <pubDate>Fri, 11 Dec 2011 13:27:27 +0100</pubDate>
      <description>Description here</description>
      <guid>http://www.somewhere2.com/pressroom/article2</guid>
      <link>http://www.somewhere2.com/pressroom/article2</link>
      <dc:creator>Someone else</dc:creator>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>Article 1</title>
      <pubDate>Fri, 09 Dec 2011 13:24:27 +0100</pubDate>
      <description>Description here</description>
      <guid>http://www.somewhere.com/pressroom/article1</guid>
      <link>http://www.somewhere.com/pressroom/article1</link>
      <dc:creator>Someone</dc:creator>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What should take priority in the merge? How is 'somewhere3.com' obtained? More info is required.

Comment: 'somewhere3.com' and other value from the merged header is obtained as a static value, ie it is always the same and obtained via c# code (I assume?) and thus not come from either file 1 or file 2. It will always stay the same.

Comment: What do you mean "should take priority"? I do not understand. The result file shows how I would like it to look like. And have the merged file have the item element sorted descendant by pubDate. Does that answer your question? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think I understand now, but it's out of my league.

Answer (score 1):

Just build the classes based on the xml structure and use serialization to load both files into objects then take the items list from one file and add them to the other and then serialize back into xml. As for the sort you would have to change the compare method for the Item class i believe, not sure haven't done it before.